# Woocommerce Sale Price function

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, wordpress

I am trying to customize the a sale/promotion I am running on a Wordpress site using Woocommerce.

In the backend admin area, I have added both a Regular price, and a sale price to to some products that are part of a promotion. When this is done, woocommerce charges the sale price in the cart right away.

Eg. ProductA  - Regular Price :$50   Sale Price: $40. 
When this product is added to the cart the sale price is used and charged ($40).

The promotion I need to run is more complex.

All products that are part of the promotion are added to a "Sale" category, and are given both the Regular price and Sale Price. But the sale price should not be applied right away for this promotion. The sale price must be only be applied per/unit instead of the regular price, if there are more than 3 of that product added to the cart for purchase.

Eg. Following ProductA above, if 1 unit of this product is added to my cart the Regular price of $50 should be calculated per unit, only if there are 3 or more units of ProductA in my cart, should the sale price of $40 per unit be calculated.

I need to try to override the current Woocommerce settings so that the sale price is only applied if that product has more than 3.

I have so far used the following code in my functions.php.

```
function check_product_in_cart() {
  //Check to see if user has product in cart
  global $woocommerce;

  // start of the loop that fetches the cart items

  foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

    // second level loop search, in case some items have several categories
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $_categoryid = $term->term_id;
    }

    if ( ($_categoryid === 17) && ($_product > 3) ) {
       //Apply sale price per unit
    }
  }
}
```

The code above should check each product in my cart, check if it in Category 17 ("Sale" category), if it is in "Sale category", check if the number of that product, if it is more than 3, apply the sale price per unit, else apply the regular price.

I have been researching this, as I believe I might need to utilize hooks and/or woocommerce filters as I am trying to safely override this feature in woocommerce.

I also looked at this for getting the products on sale:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( // Simple products type
            'key'           => '_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        ),
        array( // Variable products type
            'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'numeric'
        )
    )
);

query_posts( $args );
```

Can anyone help with this please.

Comment: Have you considered [Dynamic Pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/)?

Comment: @helgatheviking I was looking at it, but still, if it can be accomplished with code, I would prefer it as I won't need all the features of Dynamic Pricing.